# Python local variable 'message' referenced before assignment problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, local-variables

```
liquid = [l_press,l_dosage,l_bottle,l_position,l_clog,l_counter]
for j in range(len(liquid)):
        data = liquid_filling(liquid[j])
        publish.single(liquid[j],data,qos = 0, hostname = hostname,port=2259)

def liquid_filling(topic):
    if topic == "Liquid_filling/pressure":
        message = random.uniform(4.0,5.0)
    elif topic == "Liquid_filling/dosage":
        message = random.uniform(495.0,505.0)
    elif topic == "Liquid_filling/bottle_presence" or topic== "Liquid_filling/position" or topic=="Caps/position":
        if i % 2 == 0:
           message = 'YES'
        else:
           message = 'NO'
    elif topic == "Liquid_filling/counter":
        message = i
    return message
```

I receive the following error:

> Error: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment

I think that it must be something related with the alignment of the code but I have double-check it and I can't find any problem. Also, the variable message is only used to return a value.

I have already checked other related questions in this forum and I still cannot find the answer.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Think about what happens if **none of your conditions are true**... what will be the value of `message`?

Comment: Your `if` statement has no `else` clause, so there's a code path where `message` never gets defined. Consider `topic == "foo"`.

Comment: You don't have ```else``` condition, so when none of the conditions in ```if statement``` matches, you have not assigned any value to ```message```, so the return statement gives error.

Comment: They are always true because I use as input an element of a list that contains all the topics that act as conditions in this function.

Comment: And I had defined similar functions that did not have an else and they worked until I tried this one.

Comment: The error you report may not be a runtime error; you appear to be using a static analysis tool that detects the possibility that `liquid_filling` *can* be called with some other value for `topic`, even if at runtime you never do.

Comment: But if it is a runtime error, you are mistaken about `liquid_filling` only being called with the values you are checking for. Look more closely.

Comment: @cbcliff47 "They are always true because I use as input an element of a list that contains all the topics that act as conditions in this function." I don't believe you. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Even if one of the if statements *must* be true based on what is passed in (which is not a great way to design a function, but that aside...), your `message = i` statement will cause a failure because `i` is never defined. It is also a weakness that `liquid_filling` is returning an unstable value - sometimes a number, sometimes a string, maybe sometimes None? You should avoid doing that if possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it. It was that I had a topic named "Caps/position" and it should be named "Liquid_filling/position".

The code that works is as follows:

```
def liquid_filling(topic):
    if topic == "Liquid_filling/pressure":
        message = random.uniform(4.0,5.0)
    elif topic == "Liquid_filling/dosage":
        message = random.uniform(495.0,505.0)
    elif topic == "Liquid_filling/bottle_presence" or topic== "Liquid_filling/position" or topic=="Liquid_filling/anti_clogging":
        if i % 2 == 0:
           message = 'YES'
        else:
           message = 'NO'
    elif topic == "Liquid_filling/counter":
        message = i
    else: 
        message = 'There is an error'
    return message
```

Thanks for your comments because I was able to realize the problem!

Comment: Was that the problem, though, or the thing that revealed the problem?

Comment: It was said that as there is no else, when the conditions are not met, the problem is created. So then I realized that I had not well defined the conditions and I will create an else clause to inform when no conditions are met.

Comment: Great! You should probably include that code in your answer - others finding this question won't really see the solution from that description. This is why there is a focus on [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - so that the solutions can be made equally clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your case this is happening because for some reason the `topic` is not passing in your `if` conditions.

As there is no `else`, automatically when it does not pass the conditions you will not have `message` defined, causing it to not find for the return.

Make a new check of the value sent for analysis of conditions or to test that it did not pass any of the conditions, add:

```
else:
    message = 'not pass conditions'
```

And you will receive this (`not pass conditions`) value as a return, proving that it did not pass the conditions.

In short: you are looking for the problem in the wrong place in your code.